# Mapping with BizTalk + Multiple nodes to a single one

Tags: biztalk

I'm trying to make a mapping with this xml:

```
<rootxml>
  <documents>
    <document>
      <iddoc>1</iddoc>
      <total_price>1000</total_price>
    </document>
  </documents>
  <items>
    <item>
      <iddoc>1</iddoc>
      <iditem>1</iditem>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <price>800</price>
    </item>
    <item>
      <iddoc>1</iddoc>
      <iditem>2</iditem>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <price>200</price>
    </item>
  </items>
  <taxes>
    <tax>
      <iddoc>1</iddoc>
      <iditem>1</iditem>
      <idtax>1000</idtax>
      <value>123.90</value>
    <tax>
    <tax>
      <iddoc>1</iddoc>
      <iditem>2</iditem>
      <idtax>1000</idtax>
      <value>34.13</value>
    <tax>
  </taxes>
</rootxml>
```

to this one:

```
<resultxml>
  <documento>
    <iddoc>1</iddoc>
    <total_price>1000</total_price>
    <items>
      <item>
        <iddoc>1</iddoc>
        <iditem>1</iditem>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <price>800</price>
        <taxes>
          <idtax>1000</idtax>
          <value>123.90</value>
        </taxes>
      </item>
      <item>
        <iddoc>1</iddoc>
        <iditem>2</iditem>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <price>200</price>
        <taxes>
          <tax>
            <idtax>1000</idtax>
            <value>34.13</value>
          <tax>
        </taxes>
      </item>
    </items>
  </documento>
</resultxml>
```

I can't find out how to solve this. Although the original xml document can have several documents it will always have one, so I have to merge the items into it and taxes into its respective item.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to write a chunk of custom-XSLT. Loop through items/item and then build an xpath to taxes/tax[where iditem=$itemId].  The trick is to get the first itemId into the variable.

Sorry, I have limited time right now, cannot create a full working demo for you. 
Here's the related issue I had a while back: 
http://www.stylusstudio.com/ssdn/default.asp?action=9&fid=48&read=7896

Neal Walters